# how to increment the number?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[K_FS_GenerateAutoDCNo] 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @dcno VARCHAR(50), @latestindent VARCHAR(50)

  SET @dcno = (SELECT '0000')
  SET @latestindent = (SELECT dcno FROM K_FS_GenerateDcno 
                       WHERE sno = (SELECT max(sno)     
                                    FROM K_FS_GenerateDcno))

  IF EXISTS (SELECT dcno FROM K_FS_GenerateDcno WHERE dcno in (@dcno))
  BEGIN
     SELECT (@latestindent + 1) AS dcno 
  END 
  ELSE 
     SELECT (@dcno) AS dcno
END
```

It shows first time `0000`, next time it shows `1`

But I want to display `0001`..  how can I do that?

Please help me

Comment: This procedure has concurrency issues. You might get duplicated values under  [usually] heavy load.

Comment: I think there may be a small issue with your query here. After your query reaches 9999 entries, what will be next output? Even if it recycles and comes back as 0001, you may get the **PK** error. I suggest you add a timestamp or date to it. Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883196/incrementing-custom-primary-key-values-in-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883196/incrementing-custom-primary-key-values-in-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To left pad the value with `0`s up to four digits

```
RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 4) + CAST(@dcno AS VARCHAR), 4)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/27616)** demo

---

Your procedure can be boiled down to one statement

```
CREATE PROCEDURE K_FS_GenerateAutoDCNo
AS
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 4) + CAST(CAST(COALESCE(MAX(dcno), 0) AS INT) + 1 AS VARCHAR), 4) dcno
  FROM
(
  SELECT TOP 1 dcno 
    FROM K_FS_GenerateDcno
   ORDER BY sno DESC
) q;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8276/1)** demo

---

> *where i add this line..?*

In your code you can change

```
select (@latestindent + 1) as dcno
```

to

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 4) + CAST(@latestindent + 1 AS VARCHAR), 4) dcno
```

---

**Note** *such incrementing method is not concurrent safe and is a subject to race conditions.*

Comment: after 99 th number,then what happend

Comment: @SambaSiva `0100` I guess. What do you think?

Comment: yes..it's correct.. where i add this line RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 4) + CAST(@dcno AS VARCHAR), 4)

Comment: What if the values reach 9999 ? What will be the output after that?

Comment: @Mahe What do you think..? Now seriously, we can guess and ask each other all day, but it's just a matter of business requirements pure and simple. If OP's requirements tell that document number should be a left padded 4-digit integer then that's it. Of course if you have something constructive to contribute then everybody will be very grateful.

Comment: I suggest that adding a timestamp or alike along with the padded digits will solve the concurrency issue @peterm .. Here, have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883196/incrementing-custom-primary-key-values-in-sql